# Linux - start evert terminal with same lines

Tags: linux, terminal

I want my linux terminals to start with the following lines punched in:

```
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? This is some corporate remote linux server (exceedx brand).

Comment: These look like directives for a shell, not for a terminal (see [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618)). What is the shell then?

Comment: hmm, your question is above my paygrade, but this is what it looks like https://i.imgur.com/qAcif7j.png

Comment: I found an app called "GNOME character map", is "gnome" the right answer?